# Download .json file from URL to Object

Tags: c#, json

I need to download this URL to a json so I can convert it to an object.

When I run the below code though, the string comes back as "".

URL: https://data.ny.gov/resource/d6yy-54nr.json

What am I doing wrong?

Note: Code is in VB.net and object is in C# (which shouldn't matter)

```
    Protected Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Try
            Dim result = DownloadAndSerializedJsonFromUrl(Of a27baseball.Common.Objects.Oreo.DownloadJsonPowerball)("https://data.ny.gov/resource/5xaw-6ayf.json")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function DownloadAndSerializedJsonFromUrl(Of T As New)(ByVal url As String) As T
        Using w = New WebClient()
            Dim json_data = String.Empty

            Try
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url)
            Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
                Response.Write(__unusedException1__.ToString())
            End Try

            Return If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(json_data), New T())
        End Using
    End Function
```

```
namespace a27baseball.Common.Objects.Oreo
{
    public class DownloadJsonPowerball
    {
        public string draw_date { get; set; }

        public string winning_numbers { get; set; }

        public string multiplier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `json_data` (checked in `Immediate Window`)?

Comment: Okay sorry, now I'm seeing this error: `System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:` An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at  So maybe their website is stopping me from calling it?

Comment: They are likely blocking your `UserAgent` or IP address. Try altering the `UserAgent` or running the code from a different IP address.

Comment: Let me see what I can figure out. Maybe I have to call it from an IP address from New York?

Comment: I got an API key via their website, now I can't seem to find how to add it to the key to pass it across?

Comment: @mjwills I posted my direct answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% Correct Answer:

I was missing this line of code:

```
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
```

Final code:

```
   Private Function DownloadAndSerializedJsonFromUrl(Of T As New)(ByVal url As String) As T
        Using w = New WebClient()
            Dim json_data = String.Empty

            Try
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
                json_data = w.DownloadString(url)
            Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
                Response.Write(__unusedException1__.ToString())
            End Try

            Return If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(json_data), New T())
        End Using
    End Function
```

The JSON data is not present in the string and I can convert it with the JsonConver DeserializeObject method!

Thanks everyone!

Article that assisted with finding the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f22627977%2fthe-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send

Answer (score 1):

You should deserialize into `List<a27baseball.Common.Objects.Oreo.DownloadJsonPowerball>` type rather than `a27baseball.Common.Objects.Oreo.DownloadJsonPowerball` type. Since the json file content contains an array of your object type.

```
 Dim result = DownloadAndSerializedJsonFromUrl(Of List(Of a27baseball.Common.Objects.Oreo.DownloadJsonPowerball))("https://data.ny.gov/resource/5xaw-6ayf.json")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void Json()
            {
                string url = "https://data.ny.gov/resource/d6yy-54nr.json";
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                WebResponse reply;
                reply = request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader returninfo = new StreamReader(reply.GetResponseStream());
                string getinfo = returninfo.ReadToEnd();
                List<Draw> Info = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Draw>>(getinfo);
                foreach (var info in Info)
                {



                }
 public class Draw
    {
        public DateTime draw_time { get; set; }
        public string winning_numbers { get; set; }
        public string multiplier { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried like this maybe it can help.

Comment: it fails on this line `reply = request.GetResponse()` with the error: `System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) `. How were you able to get around this?

Comment: Thats weird I don't get any error. Maybe in your project you have another connection open at the sametime or you don't have access the json data in that site.

Comment: let me try again later. I tried it at work and at home and both failed :/

Comment: I posted my direct answer. Thank you for your help!